# .animate callback in other .animate load 2 times

Tags: jquery, callback, scrolltop

I want to do this:

1. scroll to 440 from the top
2. open `#detail` with animation
3. load my `id.html` inside `#detail`
4. made a CSS animation on this HTML content

I want to do this step by step:

step 2/ is executed after step 1/

step 3/ is executed after step 2/

step 4/ is executed after step 3/

But I have one problem : my `.load` function is executed twice. I don't understand why.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:(440)}, 1300,'easeInSine', function() {
    $('#detail').animate({height: detail_height}, 800, function() {
        $('#detail').load('pages/web/' + id + '.html', function() {
            //do something
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you animate `n` elements, the callback will happen `n` times. that's the intended behavior.

If you wish to get a single callback for animating multiple elements, use a promise object.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:(440)}, 1300,'easeInSine').promise().done(function() {
    $('#detail').animate({height: detail_height}, 800, function() {
        $('#detail').load('pages/web/' + id + '.html', function() {
            //do something
        });
    });
});
```

The alternative is to only select html or body, not both.